# Compare two branches in git with kdiff3

Tags: git

I would like to compare two branches with kdiff3 the command I am running is
in the folder and branch I want to compare

> git diff master

This pulls up a command-line diff but I want to use kdiff3

This is my .gitconfig

```
[user]
    name = XXXXX
    email = XXXXX
[diff]
    tool = kdiff3
    guitool = kdiff3
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
    cmd = C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
    trustExitCode = false
[difftool]
    prompt = false
    keepBackup = false
    trustExitCode = false
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3
[mergetool]
        prompt = false
    keepBackup = false
        keepTemporaries = false
[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    excludesfile = C:/Users/XXXXX/.gitignore_global
    path = C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
    trustExitCode = false
[core]
    editor = \"C:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" --wait
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: To use a difftool the command is `git difftool master`

Comment: A very useful option to `difftool` with graphical viewers is : `git difftool -d master`. Opens diff viewer in "folder comparison" mode